# Structure theorems for modules over 'good' rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, modules

Structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over PID is well-known fact.
But is there similar theorems for modules(maybe finitely-generated) over noetherian or artin or some other 'good' rings? I particularly want to know it in case $M$ is graded or have finite length.

Comment: The structure of finitely generated modules over finite dimensional algebras over fields can be very complicated, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5895/what-are-tame-and-wild-hereditary-algebras

Answer (score 1):

Things are not so simple in the generalcase. Even for Dedekind rings, which are very close to PIDs — rings of integers of algebraic number fields, are not necessarily PIDs, but they are always Dedekind rings. Any ideal of such a ring is the product of a finite number of prime ideals, and the decomposition is unique up to the order of factors.

As for PIDs a finitely generated module is the direct sum of its torsion submodule and a finitely generated torsion-free submodule. However the torsion-free part is no more a free submodule, but only a direct summand of a free module  — which is known as a (finitely generated) *projective* module. For more details, you can take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Finitely_generated_modules_over_a_Dedekind_domain).

Answer (score 1):

Yoshitomo Baba and Kiyoichi Oshiro in their book "Classical Artinian Rings and Related Topics"in Theorem 3.1.12. verify that over a Harada ring, every right R-module can be expressed as a direct sum of an in-
jective module and a small module. It may be heplfull for YOU.